# Horowitz lab 4.4

Tags: transistors, saturation, emitter-follower

I have a problem doing lab 4.4 from Horowitz's student manual for the Art of Electronics. Here's the circuit

[image: lab 4.4 circuit]

and here's what I get from LTspice simulation, which corresponds to hardware circuit behavior, having 10V sine wave at the signel input

[image: simulation result]

And the problem is that I've spent a considerable amount of time trying to analyse why it works like this but I've got just very vague understanding of it.
Particularly, I'm trying to understand why the whole signal is pushed down even at the base. Here's how I see it.

Primarily, when the signal at the base tries to climb above ~16V the transistor enters in saturation mode due to which the voltage at the emitter
stays at ~15V and at the base at ~16V.

Here the first question rises because my expectation would be that the voltage at the base follows the input (i. e. rises till 17.5V) and a huge amount of current through the base-emitter junction should burn the transistor.
So, apparently, my comprehension of saturation mode is not good and I need someone to explain me what exactly happens in transistor in this case - what are the "mechanics" of the transistor in this circuit. Also, it would be great to have some information sources giving solid understanding of the transitor saturation, maybe with real life examples.

Next point is the capasitor. I see that till the signal starts going down the transistor's base provide a kind of stiff voltage which blocks signal offsetign circuit from it's normal behavior and eventually changes the offset voltage. But this vision is to much hazy too: I can't see how it could be derived from capasitor characteristic equasion, what physical laws are involed and how exactly etc.

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: This was to painful to read. I stopped half way through. It's just one giant block of text. Paragraphs REALLY help with readability. Also, some of your sentences don't make any sense. I don't even know what you are trying to say.

Comment: i didn't read the whole thing.  but the circuit is a voltage follower.  no *voltage gain*.  or no dB of gain, the voltage gain of the amplifier is 1.0 .  so if your input is a 10 volt peak-to-peak sinusoid, the output peak-to-peak cannot exceed it, even if it were perfectly linear.  because of clipping on the top or the bottom, the peak-to-peak should come out even less,  but you have 15 volts p-p coming out.  so you have more than 10v p-p going in.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson Sorry, I didn't say it's 10v from 0 - so, 20v p-p

Comment: @efox29 All my sentences have sense for me. Be more specific - this really helps - I can try to reformulate my thoughts

Comment: well, then you're gonna clip if the power supply is 0 and 15v.  without an inductor in the circuit, there is no way your output can exceed the *"rails"*.  so the best you can expect is 14v p-p and that's only if you're perfectly biased.  it's close, i would guess it's as good as 12 volts p-p.  there should be no offset problems with DC in the source.  and if the frequency is high enough (you have to figure out what the low end -3 dB corner frequency is, and your test frequency has to be a bit higher).  i am guessing the bottom corner frequency is around 3 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the biasing pair into the Thevenin:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkbBjQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This strongly suggests that the base is near \$8\:\textrm{V}\$ and that the emitter resistor is yielding a quiescent collector current operating at about \$1\:\textrm{mA}\$. Digging in just a little more, and assuming typical \$\beta\approx 200\$ and \$V_{BE}\approx 680\:\textrm{mV}\$ for a small signal BJT (though it certainly may be a power BJT, too), I'd estimate the base current is \$I_B\approx 4\:\frac{2}{3}\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and therefore \$V_B\approx 7\:\frac{2}{3}\:\textrm{V}\$. This means \$V_E\approx 7\:\textrm{V}\$ and \$I_C\approx 933\:\mu\textrm{A}\$. So my quick estimate wasn't far afield for the quiescent state of the small signal BJT case.

Of course, that assumes there's no clipping.

Also in this case, the input capacitor will develop a standing voltage across it -- just enough so that the base can still sit at \$7\:\frac{2}{3}\:\textrm{V}\$ with the input signal at \$0\:\textrm{V}\$. So that will eventually become the input capacitor's standing voltage. The RC constant is about \$70\:\textrm{ms}\$. So I'd expect the standing voltage across the input capacitor to settle down after about 4 or 5 of those periods -- certainly in less an a half-second or so.

However, you have an input signal at \$V_{PK}= 10\:\textrm{V}\$ (or \$V_{PP}=20\:\textrm{V}\$.) I think you can immediately tell that there will be clipping. The only question is to put a quantity on it. To do so, we only have to see that \$-10\:\textrm{V}+7\:\frac{2}{3}\:\textrm{V}=-2\:\frac{1}{3}\:\textrm{V}\$. So I'd expect the capacitor's standing voltage to be about \$7\:\frac{2}{3}\:\textrm{V}-2\:\frac{1}{3}\:\textrm{V}=5\:\frac{1}{3}\:\textrm{V}\$. The clipping will start when the base is \$680\:\textrm{mV}\$. Or when \$V_{IN}\lt \left(680\:\textrm{mV}-5\:\frac{1}{3}\:\textrm{V}\right)\approx -4.65\:\textrm{V}\$, in your case. Clearly, this means the bottoms are still clipped pretty strongly even after allowing time for the input capacitor to settle down. (It also means there could be some worry for the potential for zener breakdown of the BE junction, as well, as small signal BJTs can't support much reverse voltage.)

So I don't find it at all surprising to see clipping on the bottom end.

On the top side here, it is an emitter follower. So long as the input capacitor can supply enough current the top side will probably look okay.

All the above assumes the output is unloaded, as shown, and that the input has low source impedance.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. There's a couple of questions. Does "standing voltage" mean potential difference between capasitor's plates?
If my understanding is right, your formula \$-10V + 7 \frac{2}{3}V = -2\frac{1}{3}V\$ describes the voltage appearing at the capasitor's right plate when the input signal equals to \$10V\$ and I suppose that the capasitor standing voltage is \$7\frac{2}{3}V\$.
But then, looking at the formula \$7\frac{2}{3}V - 2\frac{1}{3}V = 5\frac{1}{3}V\$ I can't see what exactly happens - why the capasitor's standing voltage changes.

Comment: @Ruslan The standing (quiescent) voltage across the input capacitor _in your circuit_ and _when you apply a \$20\:\textrm{V}_{PP}\$ to the input_ will be in the rough neighborhood of \$5\frac{1}{3}\:\textrm{V}\$. Not any of the other numbers you picked up. But if you apply a much smaller input signal, the standing voltage will be rather different -- the \$7\frac{2}{3}\:\textrm{V}\$ then shows up across the capacitor (when the signal is well below the output clipping level.)